# Editing tags when there's long tag names breaks the edit box

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, edits

This can best be displayed with an example.

When the question has a lot of long tags the <kbd>edit tags</kbd> button wraps over to a new line.

> [image: edit tags button wraps]

Clicking on it most of the tags disappear to the left of the box

> [image: tags disappear]

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594568/serverless-internet-tools-for-collaborative-development) is the question in question, from which I've removed one of the tags thereby breaking the perfect example (sorry but [collaboration](/questions/tagged/collaboration) is complete crap). [Here's another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114468/if-i-force-ie-8s-developer-tools-to-be-browser-mode-ie-8-and-document-mode) that demonstrates the same problem.

It seems to happen when the combined length of the tags is 99 or greater. The same behaviour occurs on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498579/microsoft-visual-web-developer-2010-express-class-not-registered-error-when-tr), which has a total length of 99 but not on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006538/problem-on-one-to-many-relationships-entity-framework-4-1-mvc) where the length is 98.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutly the intended behavior. If the tags are longer than the tag edit box, you have to have some sort of scrolling. This is exactly how a normal textbox behaves when the content is longer than the box is wide – some things disappear on the left or right, and  you have to use the cursor/Home/End keys to get around.

Comment: I would normally expect them to disappear off in the other direction, if they have to, but fair enough :-).

Comment: Then the cursor (which is at the end) wouldn't be visible.